# CS2012 Cannot Open .exe for writing - Access to path is denied

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am trying to create a WPF project for the first time using VS2017 v15.8.

I am getting the error message consistently, although there are times I have been able to get it to run. When I go to run it again though I receive the error message. I have read all of the proposed solutions and nothing has worked including the following:

Restart computer
Rebuild the solution/project. (tried deleting .exe file before doing this also)
Confirmed the Output path is correct
Kill the MSBuild process tree

I also tried different combinations.

Any help in finding a solution to this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Time to go shopping for a different anti-malware product.  Do favor the one included with the OS.

Answer (score 1):

That typically happens to me, when i forget to stop my running program.  As the executable is running, it is open and hence should not be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to work around this. The issues I was having occurred when I was trying to save the project to a network drive or to the default location in my user profile on the local drive. I tried creating it again and saved it in a root folder on the local drive it worked.